# Adding same type accounts from two different applications

Tags: android, accountmanager

I have two different applications (WEB clients for my own site) and it must using same accounts to authenticate on my WEB service. I write library for that task and include it to both applications. This library using AccountManager and implemented by analogy with [Udinic's example](http://udinic.wordpress.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/).

But here is one problem. I am installing both application on one device. And I can add account only from one of my application (which was installed first). In second application AccountManager.addAccount() doesn't work (AccountManagerCallback doesn't called and getResult() nothing to do). How to do that both applications could add accounts with one type?

Comment: Please clarify the "doesn't work" part.

Comment: @Egor, question updated. Doesn't work mean that the callback doesn't launch and getResult() nothing to do, just waiting infinity.